# Convert an object in a list to a string

Tags: c#, list, object

I want to change my first property in a list which is for example 5 to a string like this: " " --> (that it's just a space). I want this specific entry of the list to be empty...

The code below is causing an error:

> "An implicit conversion from type "string" to "double" is not
>   possible"

**My Code:**

```
var mylist = new List<myclass>();
// ...
var obj = mylist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.myproperty == this.myproperty);
if (obj != null) obj.myproperty = " ";
```

**My Class**

```
class myclass
{
    public int laufzeit { get; set; }

    public double myproperty { get; set; }

    public double darlehensbetrag { get; set; }      
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what the List data type is?

Comment: Do you well understand the difference between an `double` and a `string` ?

Comment: The question is, why do you want to write a string " " into your "myproperty"? Do you just want to "null" it?

Comment: Nulling would also be possible, I generate a datagrid view with my list and in the first row I want to change the value of the property

Comment: Ok, If it's a `double` what do you expect when you try to assign it to space `" "`? What is the expected result? Is space a number?

Comment: @Vincent: What is your target? Why do you want to write a " " space into your prop?

Comment: im rebuildung a calculator for annuity's, the first row of the table contains some data, but the value of my property should just appear in the second row of the datagrid view, to  which I parse my list. The first entry should be just nothing, thanks a lot for the support...

Comment: I not really sure if I get your target, but it is not possible to write a string into a double. Create a additional prop for your output of type string and convert your double into string.

Comment: ok thank you, I just thought it's possible to convert this specific entry in my list to a string or to make it empty

Answer (score 1):

You can't store a space in a number field, but you can make your class clever enough to sometimes display a number and sometimes display a space.

```
class myclass
{
    public bool ShowSpace { get; set; }

    public double myproperty { get; set; }

    public override ToString()
    {
        return this.ShowSpace ? " " : this.myproperty.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states you wan't to assign the `string` value `" "` to a `double` property. This isn't possible, since a `string` is never a `double`. A `string` can be used to *display* a `double`, but it's still a `string`, that just *looks* like a `double`.

However such a string can be converted into a double:

```
string numberString = "5.7";
double number = double.Parse(numberString);
```

Note that the snippet above will throw an exception, if `numberString` can't be converted intro a double, e.g. when the string is `" "`.

What you're trying is to change the *Type* of a property at runtime. That is not possible, since c# is a strongly typed language. You can't have a class that looks like

```
class Foo
{
    double Bar {get; set;}
}
```

and then magically transforms at runtime into

```
class Foo
{
    string Bar {get; set;}
}
```

You could bypass this using `object` or `dynamic` as type of `Bar`, but i highly recommend **not** to do so. Since is bypasses the whole idea of using types. In such a case you never know, wheter is `Bar` a `double` or a `string`.

I do not really understand, *why* you want this, but in my opinion it looks a bad design and maybe an other solution is appropiate.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think you're right another solution is the best way. I thought I could easily enter this one field in my list and just change it's type.